# My code for webscraping media with python from a game is not working for me,

Tags: python

I have been trying to download pictures and audio from this web based game. It has not yet worked for me. Is there any way I can get help here, even if it is a tutorial?

```
import re 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_images(site):
    """ Extract images from the url given"""
    response=requests.get(site)

    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml.parser')

    image_tags=soup.find_all('image')


    # extract the urls
    urls=[image['src'] for img in img_tags]

    for url in urls:
        pattern=r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$' # pattern to extract image files

        filename=re.search(pattern, url)

        if not filename:
            print("No filename {}", url)
            continue

        with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
            if 'http' not in url:       # relative reques?
                url="{}{}".format(site, url)

            print(url)

            response=requests.get(url)
            f.write(response.content)


if __name__=="__main__":
    site="https://heartofvegasslots.productmadness.com/"

    extract_images(site)
```

Comment: What happens with your code?

Comment: It is not extracting the images that are in the website, When I run it, it only gives me the prompt symbols. I dont know how to further proceed

Answer (score 0):

Great start on it and almost had it working.

There are a couple of lines that you should change to get it working.
First:  This line needs wont work in its current form as the list comprehension is calling the wrong variables

```
`urls=[image['src'] for img in img_tags]`
```

also if you call `image['src']` and 'src' doesnt exist it will fail.  try instead using the `get` method.

maybe try something like this:

```
`urls=[img.get('src') for img in image_tags]`
```

Second line

`image_tags=soup.find_all('image')`

to

`image_tags=soup.find_all('img')`

I have changed it to 'img' instead of 'image' as those are the name of the html tags for images.

I couldnt get it working for the website provided, but that looks like it doesnt have any img tags.

This is my code, and a website that i have tried with it working.

```
import re 
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_images(site):
    """ Extract images from the url given"""
    response=requests.get(site)

    soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')


    image_tags=soup.find_all('img')
    print(image_tags)

    # extract the urls
    urls=[img.get('src') for img in image_tags]

    for url in urls:
        if url:
            pattern=r'/([\w_-]+[.](jpg|gif|png))$' # pattern to extract image files

            filename=re.search(pattern, url)

            if not filename:
                print("No filename {}", url)
                continue

            with open(filename.group(1), 'wb') as f:
                print(f'writing {filename}')
                if 'http' not in url:       # relative reques?
                    url="{}{}".format(site, url)

                print(url)

                response=requests.get(url)
                f.write(response.content)


if __name__=="__main__":
    site="https://antennatestlab.com/"
    extract_images(site)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the input,

Comment: I would like some further help on the website, do you think there is a way to web scrape the images in this website as it has the pictures named (images) and audio in the tag(audio). they are all under the (media). Do you think it is possible to get the images and audio from it?

Comment: this is the website